# How to select label for checked checkbox using CSS?

Tags: css, html

I'm composing a stringbuilder on serverside (HTML code) and by ajax sending a response to jquery function that puts this HTML in place. On serverside is decided which checkbox will be checked. So far so good.

I would like to select labels for checked checkboxes and change colour so checked countries would be differently coloured. My trouble is that I can't select desired labels and change color property. I tried with this what you see and of course using classes and `+` and `>` and `:before` and other weird things...

So, how to select them and change any property on the label?

I would like to do it using CSS, I know how to do it using jquery but it seems so wrong.

```css
label + input.chkCountry[type="checkbox"]:checked  {color:green;}
```

```html
<ul class="chkbox">
  <li><label class="lblCountry" for="chkCC_AF"><input type="checkbox" class="chkCountry" id="chkCC_AF" name="chk_AF" value="AF" checked="checked">Afghanistan</label></li>
  <li><label class="lblCountry" for="chkCC_AL"><input type="checkbox" class="chkCountry" id="chkCC_AL" name="chk_AL" value="AL">Albania</label></li>
  <li><label class="lblCountry" for="chkCC_DZ"><input type="checkbox" class="chkCountry" id="chkCC_DZ" name="chk_DZ" value="DZ">Algeria</label></li>
  <li><label class="lblCountry" for="chkCC_AS"><input type="checkbox" class="chkCountry" id="chkCC_AS" name="chk_AS" value="AS">American Samoa</label></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You only need to change the HTML and selector. In CSS the label doesn't know if the checkbox is checked so you have to turn it around.

```css
input.chkCountry[type="checkbox"]:checked + label  {color:green;}
/*input:checked + label  {color:green;} /* Short selector */
```

```html
<ul class="chkbox">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="chkCountry" id="chkCC_AF" name="chk_AF" value="AF" checked="checked">   
    <label class="lblCountry" for="chkCC_AF">Afghanistan</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="chkCountry" id="chkCC_AL" name="chk_AL" value="AL">
    <label class="lblCountry" for="chkCC_AL">Albania</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="chkCountry" id="chkCC_DZ" name="chk_DZ" value="DZ">
    <label class="lblCountry" for="chkCC_DZ">Algeria</label>
  </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" class="chkCountry" id="chkCC_AS" name="chk_AS" value="AS">
    <label class="lblCountry" for="chkCC_AS">American Samoa</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If anyone else wonders if the order matters, it doesn't: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/84377/should-i-put-the-label-before-or-after-the-input-element

Comment: The order of the CSS selector matters

Comment: Should've specified, the order of HTML label - input ;)

Comment: I just want to warn about the info above that "In HTML the input shouldn't be in the label element" - this is not really true - one of HUGE advantages of input inside label, which is improving the usability - clicking the text itself acts as clicking on checkbox/radio. This can also be achieved by having the label with "for" attribute, however that one is not always so easy to use, if autogenerating some huge lists etc (always can be done, but requires additional code). Closing input in the label solves it all. But yes, round around, this generates problem to select such label parent.

Answer (score 3):

Follow below code example

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul class="chkbox">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkCC_AF" name="chk_AF" value="AF" checked="checked">
    <label class="lblCountry" for="chkCC_AF">Afghanistan</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkCC_AL" name="chk_AL" value="AL">
    <label class="lblCountry" for="chkCC_AL">Albania</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You will need to  move label after checkbox in your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Try This way:

```css
.chkCountry:checked + .lblCountry {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul class="chkbox">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="chkCountry" id="chkCC_AF" name="chk_AF" value="AF" checked="checked">
    <label class="lblCountry" for="chkCC_AF">Afghanistan</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="chkCountry" id="chkCC_AL" name="chk_AL" value="AL">
    <label class="lblCountry" for="chkCC_AL">Albania</label></li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="chkCountry" id="chkCC_DZ" name="chk_DZ" value="DZ">
    <label class="lblCountry" for="chkCC_DZ">Algeria</label></li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="chkCountry" id="chkCC_AS" name="chk_AS" value="AS">
    <label class="lblCountry" for="chkCC_AS">AAmerican Samoa</label></li>
</ul>
```